# Entity Framework 4.1 (Code First) audit column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 with a Code-First approach on an ASP.NET MVC site

Say I have an entity named **Profile** that keeps track of a user's favorite book, and I want to track when the user updates their favorite book.

**UPDATED**:

Using the class below as an example, I want to set the FavoriteBookLastUpdated property to the current date whenever the value of the FavoriteBook property changes.

```
public class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteBook { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FavoriteBookLastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I just update that field, if appropriate, in the controller's Edit action before calling the DBContext's SaveChanges() method.

Is there a way I can put that logic in my model somehow?  I'd prefer not to use triggers on the database side.

Comment: What would using triggers accomplish?

Comment: @Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck, using a SQL UPDATE trigger I could check that the FavoriteBook column is about to change, and stamp the current time in the FavoriteBookLastUpdated column.  That's exactly what I'd like to do but in code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I read your comment and new example :)

Could you not have your Favorite book property be an actual property that also sets LastModified? I'm not sure if EF4 will accept that, but then you could make a public property for changing the FavoriteBook and a special one for EF4 only. You might need to make the special property 'InternalsVisibleTo'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: +1 Yes. If you want to change another property together with currently changing it looks like a case for custom property setter doing all the stuff. That has nothing to do with EF.

Comment: @Ladislav, Perfect.  I should have just tried that from the start.  I was over-thinking this.  I created a custom public property setter (and getter) for FavoriteBook that also updates the lastupdated property.  Simple.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the @Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck's answer which I think is correct one you can try to use EF for that:

```
public override int SaveChanges() 
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Profile>())
    {
        if (entry.OriginalValues == null || // I'm not sure what value this have if entity is not loaded
            entry.Entity.FavoritBook != entry.OriginalValues["FavoriteBook"].ToString())
        {
            entry.Entity.FavoriteBookLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```